# Java Domain Design

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I've been going back and forth on the best way to design and implement a domain layer in Java while using the SpringJDBC Template. I want to design something that is going to be reusable and robust, while avoiding the n+1 query problems and performance problems. I've come up with a couple cases but not sure which one would be best for use with JDBC. I've used Hibernate previously. What is the best way to approach domain design in Java assuming SpringJDBC will be the technology interacting with the database.

As an example lets say I have an Address, which has a State, which has a Country.

Case 1: Domain object exact match to database

```
public class Address {

    private long id;
    private String streetLine1;
    private String streetLine2;
    private String city
    private long stateId;
    private String zipCode;

    ...
}

public class State {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private long countryId;
}

public class Country {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
}
```

In this case the domain objects are an exact representation of a database tables, thus row mapping is simple, and the objects can be persisted into the database.

The major downside I can see to this is, lets say on the user interface I need to list all addresses in the application, and the want Street 1, Street 2, City, State (full name), Postal Code, and Country. If there are 100 address that are returned, I then need to issue two additional queries per row to get the State object, and Country object for a ground total of 201 queries executed, OUCH!

Case 2:

Follow the same design as Case 1, but when you encounter a situation where the UI requires components from multiple domain objects, return a custom DTO object by having the RowMapper map to the DTO object instead of the domain, makes it possible to execute one query. The downside I see here is you may end up with a ton of special case DTO / Model objects.

```
public class AddressDTO {

    private long id;
    private String streetLine1;
    private String streetLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
}
```

Case 3:

Map similar to how you would in hibernate where domain objects reference each other. However now the RowMappers get more complex, and they may be fetching data unnecessarily. At that point it is expected that the objects would always be populated, since there is no lazy loading like what JPA/Hibernate can do. In order to persist and Address, the Address object would need a valid State object associated. This seems like the least practical solution but I maybe there is something I'm not understanding.

```
public class Address {

    private long id;
    private String streetLine1;
    private String streetLine2;
    private String city
    private State state;
    private String zipCode;

    ...
}

public class State {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private County country;
}

public class Country {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private Set<State> states;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Case 2 because when you need to query across domains it makes more sense to use usecase driven DTOs and use SQL Join(s) to get data from the linked domains

Comment: This made more sense to me as well.